# Calculate the matrix of the linear operator with respect to standard bases

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Calculate the matrix of the linear operator $T:\Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^3$ with respect to standard bases if $T$ displays point $A$ to a point symmetrically associated with it according to the plane $2x + 2y + z = 0$.

Comment: Note that askers are expected to provide context for their questions, [as is explained here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). For example, it would be helpful if you could [edit] your question to tell us where you encountered this question, what you have tried so far, and any other relevant thoughts you have.

Answer (score 0):

Let $v = \frac{1}{3}(2, 2, 1)$. Note that $\|v\| = 1$. The plane is $P = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^3 : (x, y, z) \cdot v = 0\}$. Geometrically, this is a plane with normal vector $v$. To reflect a point $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$ across $P$ means to negate the component of $x$ in the direction of $v$. The component of $x$ in the direction of $v$ is $(x \cdot v)v$. So the reflection of $x$ is
$$Rx = x - 2(x \cdot v)v = x - 2v v^Tx = (I - 2v v^T)x.$$
Thus $R = I - 2vv^T$.